# Simple Membership Provider Relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, relationship, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

In ASP.NET MVC 3 with Default Membership Provider I would create relationships with

```
public virtual Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
public virtual MembershipUser User
{
    get
    {
        return Membership.GetUser(UserGuid);
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET MVC 4 with Simple Membership Provider what is the equivalent method of Membership.GetUser() and class MembershipUser that are compatible with SMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the websecurity class
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_ref_websecurity.asp